# Python convert list to dict with multiple key value

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list something like below and want to convert it to dict

```
my_list = ['key1=value1', 'key2=value2', 'key3=value3-1', 'value3-2', 'value3-3', 'key4=value4', 'key5=value5', 'value5-1', 'value5-2', 'key6=value6']
```

How can I convert above list to dict something like below

```
my_dict = {
  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2',
  'key3': ['value3-1', 'value3-2', 'value3-3'],
  'key4': 'value4',
  'key5': ['value5', 'value5-1', 'value5-2'],
  'key6': 'value6'
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I tried to solve it, but kept getting IndexError.

Comment: It is a terrible idea to mix types, use lists for all the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways to do this, this is one:
EDIT:  my first solution gave a list for every value, but you only require a list when there is more than one value for a key.

```
my_list = ['key1=value1', 'key2=value2', 'key3=value3-1', 'value3-2', 'value3-3', 'key4=value4', 'key5=value5', 'value5-1', 'value5-2', 'key6=value6']

my_dict = {}
current_key = None
for item in my_list:
    if '=' in item:
        current_key, value = item.split('=')
        # This puts a string as the value
        my_dict[current_key] = value  
    else:
        # Check if the value is already a list
        if not isinstance(my_dict[current_key], list):
            # If value is not a list, create one
            my_dict[current_key] = [my_dict[current_key]]

        my_dict[current_key].append(item)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(my_dict)
```

Gives:

```
{'key1': 'value1',
 'key2': 'value2',
 'key3': ['value3-1', 'value3-2', 'value3-3'],
 'key4': 'value4',  
 'key5': ['value5', 'value5-1', 'value5-2'],
 'key6': 'value6'}
```

You might wish to make it more robust by checking if `current_key` is `None`.  I'll leave that to you.

Comment: @cdrake Thanks for this. Worked like a charm in my scenario

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pprint

my_list = ['key1=value1', 'key2=value2', 'key3=value3-1', 'value3-2',
           'value3-3', 'key4=value4', 'key5=value5', 'value5-1', 'value5-2', 'key6=value6']

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
current_key = None

for item in my_list:
    if '=' in item:
        current_key, value = item.split('=')

    my_dict[current_key].append(value)

my_dict = {k: v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in my_dict.iteritems()}

pprint.pprint(my_dict)
```

Out of curiosity, if your input was a dictionary, getting a list would be trivial:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    'key3': ['value3-1', 'value3-2', 'value3-3'],
    'key4': 'value4',
    'key5': ['value5', 'value5-1', 'value5-2'],
    'key6': 'value6'
}

output = ["{0}={1}".format(k, ', '.join(v) if type(v) is list else v)
          for k, v in my_dict.iteritems()]
print output
```

Comment: Good attempt. But I think you done reverse :)

Comment: A `dict` out of a `list` is expected

Comment: @RahulKP Lol, that's right, I hadn't even read the question, just saw some data and I didn't know which one was input or output. I've solved for both cases :')

Comment: for your both attempt +1.